# dryer vent near water pipe

Tags: vent, dryer

I'm running a dryer vent through the floor close to a water pipe and am wondering if in very cold weather the dryer vent would get cold enough from outside air (with only the plastic cover on the outside keeping out cold air) that there might be a chance of the space under the floor getting so cold that the water pipe could freeze.

The water pipes are only about 8 inches from the outside wall.

Comment: Where on this planet are you?

Answer (score 1):

If there's a damper on the outside end of the dryer vent, and the water pipes are in at least occasional use, and the space gets some heat from the rest of the house, then you should be fine.

A more detailed answer would require more information, e.g. how cold is "very cold weather", a diagram of the situation, etc.